# Cross Group By and Max Date Script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a script to pull a `Group By` and a MAX(CreatedOnDate) from two different tables but only return where table1's MAX(CreatedOnDate) is greater than table2's MAX(CreatedOnDate).

For example;

```
select MasterId, max(createdon) --Master id + latest product generated date
from product
group by MasterId

select contactId, max(createdon) --Contact id + latest edit date for that contact
from contactEdit
group by contactId

    from contactEdit ce
join contactmaster cm
    on ce.contactId = cm.contactid
join product p
    on p.MasterId = cm.MasterId
```

Between these two tables there is a contactMaster table, the join of which is above also. I want to find a list of all Contacts who have had Edits made since the last Product was created relating to that Contact.

Something like;

```
where max(ce.createdon) > max(p.createdon)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not quite sure what your tables look like and what exactly you are trying to achieve, so this is a bit of a guess.

what you want to do is group the tables in subselects and then compare the maxdates:

```
with ce as (
    select  MasterId, max(createdon) maxco --Master id + latest product generated date
    from    product
    group by MasterId
)
, prod as (
    select contactId, max(createdon) maxco --Contact id + latest edit date for that contact
    from contactEdit
    group by contactId
)
, cm as (
    select  contactId, masterId, max(createdon) maxco --Master id + latest product generated date
    from    contactmaster
    group by contactId, masterId
)
select contactId
    from ce
join cm
    on ce.contactId = cm.contactid
join product p
    on p.MasterId = cm.MasterId
where ce.maxco > prod.maxco
```